# I need to have spaces between outputted _

Tags: c++

I have just more or less finished my first C++ Project, it is a Hangman Game and so far everything works fine. The only Problem is that i need to have spaces between the underlines (_) that represent the hidden word. If anyone could help me on this i would really appreciate it.

```
// UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING LINE (REMOVE THE TWO SLASHES AT THE BEGINNING) TO RUN AUTOMATIC TESTS
#include "tests.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "hangman.h"

int main(){

    using namespace std;



    // display the hidden word
    std::string word_to_guess = chooseWord();
    int misses = 0;
    std::string displayed_word = word_to_guess;

    for(int i=0; i< displayed_word.length(); i++)
        displayed_word[i] = '_';

     int attempts = 6;    
      std::cout << "Attempts left:" << attempts << std::endl;
    std::cout << "[ " << displayed_word << " ]" << std::endl;  


    //check for correct letter

    while(1){
        std::cout << "Your guess";
        std::cout << ":";
        char guess;
        std::cin >> guess;

        bool Correct = false;
        for(int i=0; i< word_to_guess.length(); i++)
            if (guess == word_to_guess[i]) {
                displayed_word[i] = word_to_guess[i];
                Correct = true;
            }    

        if (!Correct)
            attempts--;
        if (!Correct)    
            std::cout << "Attempts left:" << attempts << std::endl;
        if (!Correct)    
            std::cout << "[ " << displayed_word << " ]" << std::endl; 


        if (Correct)    
                std::cout << "Attempts left:" << attempts << std::endl;
        if (Correct)        
             std::cout << "[ " << displayed_word << " ]" << std::endl; 


       //check for win or lose
      if (attempts==0) 
          std::cout << "The word was: " << word_to_guess << std::endl << "You lost!";
          if (attempts==0)
              return 0;

      if (!word_to_guess.find(displayed_word))
          std::cout << "You won!";
          if (!word_to_guess.find(displayed_word))
              return 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: So you want the user to be able to count the underscores? Unfortunately, as far as I know, you can't because in a usual console all characters are the same size and the smallest gap you can get is a space. Try using other characters instead of the underscore and see which one looks best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can simplify this

```
if (!Correct)    
    std::cout << "Attempts left:" << attempts << std::endl;
if (!Correct)    
    std::cout << "[ " << displayed_word << " ]" << std::endl; 

if (Correct)    
    std::cout << "Attempts left:" << attempts << std::endl;
if (Correct)        
    std::cout << "[ " << displayed_word << " ]" << std::endl;
```

by this

```
std::cout << "Attempts left:" << attempts << std::endl;
std::cout << "[ " << displayed_word << " ]" << std::endl;
```

---

Now, about your question, I think a best solution is replacing

```
std::cout << "[ " << displayed_word << " ]" << std::endl;
```

by this

```
std::cout << "[";
for(int i = 0; i < displayed_word.length(); i++) {
    if(i == 0 || displayed_word[i] == '_')
        std::cout << " ";
    std::cout << displayed_word[i];
    if(i == displayed_word.length()-1 || (displayed_word[i] == '_' && displayed_word[i+1] != '_'))
        std::cout << " ";
}
std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
```

---

*Explaination:*

We put spaces at the beginning and the end, and also around underscores, but we make sure to put only one space between two underscores.

Comment: I made an edit, make sure to try with the new version of my code.